# Unknown pest on a mint

Tags: pests, mint

I have some mint plants that suffer from some kind of tumor disease or parasite. I have not found any helpful information about what this is. I searched for images of mint pathogens, but nothing similar was found. Google Lens did not help either.

We just touched one of those tumors, and it suddenly released some kind of spores.

What am I looking at?

[image: mint]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is mint rust, a fungal infection. The yellow spots look a bit like [here](https://www.shootgardening.co.uk/plant/disease/mint-rust).

You can better remove the infected plant, or parts of the plant to prevent further infection.

Comment: We thought so, too. But I didn't find any photos of mint rust with such extreme tumors.

Comment: You said it released spores, better remove it before it spreads.

Comment: Already done!!!